# How to prevent an object looking jitterly in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have a simple object with a dynamic rigidbody, moving it horizontally. And my camera with a kinematic rigidbody is following that object. But it is looking very jittery despite interpolation.

Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;
    public float offset;

    public Rigidbody2D ballRig;
    public Rigidbody2D cameraRig;

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            ballRig.gravityScale *= -1;
            ballRig.velocity *= 0.6f;
        }

        ballRig.position = new Vector2(ballRig.position.x + speed * Time.deltaTime, ballRig.position.y);
        cameraRig.position = new Vector2(ballRig.position.x + offset, 0);
    }
}
```

How it looks:
[image: Jittery movement of the object]

How can I solve this problem without using 'ease-in & ease-out' solution?

Comment: Why do you set camera position in first instance ?

Comment: To follow the object, the camera gets moved to object's position automatically by `cameraRig.position = new Vector2(ballRig.position.x + offset, 0);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Camera following Rigidbody jitter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52700255/1092820)